# how to select and sort in sqlite and js

Tags: sqlite

Hi I have the following table

```
buildingcode flatname flatdescription date
01           A 1      name 1          12-2012
01           B 2      name 1          12-2012
02           A 0      name 2          12-2012
01           A 1      name 1          11-2012
```

I want to display as follow

```
B 2   name 1
A 1   name 1
```

And to explain what I want to do:

display only buildingcode 01,

display once by flatname,

sort by flatname desc

What is the sqlite command to do this?

I try this but the order is wrong

```
'SELECT DISTINCT flatdescription, flatname, buildingcode FROM bill WHERE buildingcode = ? '
```

Please advice

Comment: what does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: `select distinct` applies to the whole row. you'd most likely want to group on buildingcode or something.

Comment: `order by` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: how to use order by with select distinct

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT flatname, flatdescription
FROM bill
WHERE buildingcode = '01'
ORDER BY flatname DESC
```

Comment: I want to display once every flatname

Comment: And how is that different from the result of this query?